# How can i start DB2 using crontab in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: bash, db2, ubuntu-14.04

Actully i'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and DB2 10.5 version

I need to start and stop db2 with a particular time every day using crontab in Ubuntu

**My crontab code**

```
# Testing Crons
1 * * * * db2inst1 ./db2start
```

i tried this code but it's not working..

Is there any sample code for this process. kindly advice me.

Comment: Use full path - `1 * * * * db2inst1 /where/it/is/db2start`

Comment: ... and use full path to `db2inst1`